# PHP Display an array in table format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table

I have an array like below, I need to display that array into table. I have tried the function using PHP but it getting rows and cells value, I need three type of values:

1. Rows name
2. Columns name
3. name for the corresponding row and column

Note : I have convert the below array1 into  array 2

**Array 1 :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array ([id] => 1[rows] => R1[columns] => c1[name] => 1)
    [1] => Array([id] => 2[rows] => R1[columns] => c2[name] => 2)
    [2] => Array([id] => 3[rows] => R1[columns] => c3[name] => 3)
    [3] => Array([id] => 4[rows] => R2[columns] => c1 [name] => 1)
    [4] => Array([id] => 5[rows] => R2[columns] => c2[name] => 2)
    [5] => Array([id] => 6[rows] => R2[columns] => c3[name] => 3)
)
```

**Array 2 :**

```
 Array
        (    
          [0] => Array([0] => R1[1] => c1[2] => 1)
          [1] => Array([0] => R1[1] => c2[2] => 2)
          [2] => Array([0] => R1[1] => c3[2] => 3)
          [3] => Array([0] => R2[1] => c1[2] => 1)
          [4] => Array([0] => R2[1] => c2[2] => 2)
          [5] => Array([0] => R2[1] => c3[2] => 3)
        )
```

Table :

```
    id | row | column | value
    --------------------------
    1  | r1  |  c1    |  1
    2  | r1  |  c2    |  2
    3  | r1  |  c3    |  3
    4  | r2  |  c1    |  1
    5  | r2  |  c2    |  2
    6  | r2  |  c3    |  3
```

Function : This function convert the array2 into table

```
function convetTable($array) {
      $rows = array(); 
      $rows[0] = array(); 
      foreach ($array as $column) { 
        if (!in_array($column[1],$rows[0])) {
            $rows[0][] = $column[1]; 
        }
      }
      $count = count($rows[0]);
      foreach ($array as $row) {
        $rowTtl = $row[0];
        $rowQty = $row[1];
        $rowVal = $row[2];
        if (!isset($rows[$rowTtl])) $rows[$rowTtl] = array_pad(array(),$count,0);
                $rows[$rowTtl][array_search($rowQty,$rows[0])] = $rowVal;
       }
    return $rows;
 }

$table = convetTable($array2);

HTML :

{foreach from=$table item=key key=foo}
                        <tr class="prototype" id="first_row">
                        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove">Remove Row</a>
                        <td><input type="text" name="rows[]" value="{$foo}" class="number" /></td>
                        {foreach from=$key item=cell}
                            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="cols[]" value="{$cell}" class="id number" /></td>
                         {/foreach}
                        </tr>
                   {/foreach}
```

**Expected OutPut**

```
0   C1 C2 C3

R1  1  2  3

R2  1  2  3
```

PS : here c1,c2,c3,1,2,3 are $cell value.

What I try to display $row,$col,$name, but here I'm getting $row and $cell only.

I need another value name for the corresponding row and column.

Comment: this much big code just to put an array to a table?

Comment: You need to explain more. Where are `values` in your array? What does the current function do? Example of how your table needs to be displayed? Please observe that it's not very helpful to just dump your code and have us go through it to understand what it's doing.

Comment: @ I Can Has Cheezburger  @NishantSolanki I have edited my exact question

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
$count = count($array); //this will give you the count of elements of your array...
echo "<table border="1"><tr><th>ID</th><th>ROWS</th><th>COLUMNS</th><th>NAMES</th></tr>";
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) //loop through the array..
{
    echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>".$array[$i][0]."</td><td>".$array[$i][1]."</td><td>".$array[$i][2]."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Please note this code is to show you how to simplify your massiave code... may be you will need to edit this code to get the desired output...